# CSS:  body { } Selector not Working

Tags: html, css

This is the whole document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body‌ {
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 8px;
            background: #f00;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    Sample Text
    <p>Another Text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HDBqZ/

Why it's not working? Am I missing something?

Comment: Interestingly, `html{...}` works. Did you try with external styles?

Comment: your code is just perfect , i just deleted some spaces and it worked

Comment: You have a weird character after `body`: [`U+200c`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There seems to be some [junk](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm) after the `y` in your `body {` selector:

```
>>> u'body‌'
u'body\u200c'
```

Delete your `body` line and re-write it by hand. Your text editor should have some tool to get rid of these things automatically as well.

Comment: You can validate the whole document here: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input ... It is valid.

Comment: Great spot, this fixed it for me. Just delete the opening body tag and rewrite, then delete the body selector and rewrite and it works.

Comment: @Natasha: It might be valid, but your selector tries to match a tag that does not exist. If you copy the CSS here: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/, you can see at the bottom of the validation: `bodyâ {`

Comment: @Natasha: It is valid. The problem is that your selector is looking for `<body\u200c>` tags.

Comment: The junk is U+200C ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER, an invisible control character, which is (like any non-Ascii Unicode character) allowed in an identifier in CSS syntax. This is why the CSS Validator does not catch this error – it is not an error in CSS terms! The selector is a five-character identifier, `body` followed by U+200C, and this selector matches no element.

Comment: @Blender umm... `<body\u200c>` tags look like invalid HTML. Valid CSS that only matches invalid HTML sounds weird :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: I tried it locally and it worked. I copy-pasted the zero width character after the `body` in the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: That doesn't matter - they're two separate languages. CSS does not care whether your HTML is invalid (and for that matter neither does HTML care whether your CSS is invalid). It may seem weird, but that's how it is.

Comment: @Jan: `foo {...}` would match elements with tag `foo` which is invalid HTML as well ;) CSS and HTML are independent.

Comment: Just curious, what ide are you using? notepadd++ show ? after body - removed and works.

Comment: @Blender doesn't make it any more valid :-) Browsers are required to interpret unknown tags as unstyled inline elements. By an old HTML spec, at least.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: "Browsers are required to interpret unknown tags as unstyled inline elements" ... to which style rules may then be applied. Doesn't make it any more relevant to CSS, which is what we're talking about here, not HTML.

Comment: @JanDvorak: I don't see anything in the HTML5 spec that forbids unicode characters, but Chrome does treat it as a separate inline element: http://i.imgur.com/oFwThFh.png